# Issues with vi command over expect/spawn ssh session

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, expect

I am running Xubuntu 16.04. I have an expect command to connect to a remote centos server using ssh. I did this to automate the authentication information which I used to manually enter earlier. After connecting to the server, I am able to use the `vi` command to edit files, and that works only for a few minutes. After sometime, if I use `vi`, whatever I enter on the command line gets messed up and does not occur at the correct cursor place where I am typing. I face the same issue when using `mysql` command line. I am able to type in queries or paste the already copied queries fine only for few minutes, after which whatever I type or paste gets messed up on the command line screen. Is this a known issue when using expect command? Is there a fix?

Comment: Are you referring to using the session after an expect `interact` command? are you re-sizing the terminal at some point?

Comment: This question may be better asked on Stack Overflow. You might want to flag a moderator to get the question moved.

Comment: I suspect you need to trap and pass the SIGWINCH signal - see for example [Exploring Expect: A Tcl-based Toolkit for Automating Interactive Programs](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Jk2bAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA315&ots=KrKz4-BT9f&dq=expect%20trap%20winch%20slave&pg=PA315#v=onepage&q=expect%20trap%20winch%20slave&f=false)